# Integration with AWS using c# dot net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am trying to connect Amazon Web service to with C# dot net application. I have followed steps from below link:

[Amazon product advertising api - c# sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765959/amazon-product-advertising-api-c-sharp-sample?answertab=active#tab-top)

I have created an Amazon associate account.

I have created an account on Amazon Web Service.

I have followed so many tutorials available online but none worked for me i always get below error:

I get an error: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

Please suggest me what is wrong in my configuration.

Comment: Is there anything i have to configure in my amazon associate account or amazon web service?

Comment: You are using the [Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) nuget package?